# Java+Spring5: handling file uploads non-blocking

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a web app using Java and Spring 5 which will be able to handle file uploads in a non-blocking fashion.

There are tons of docs and examples on how to handle regular requests in a non-blocking fashion, but I can't find neat example on how to handle a file upload.

I found something more or less relevant to this, but it looks too combersome:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart
- https://github.com/synchronoss/nio-multipart/blob/master/integration-tests/src/main/java/org/synchronoss/cloud/nio/multipart/example/web/MultipartController.java

Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: any updates?:) also seeking ideas for this